# menubar tooltip not showing for all elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

For my app I want to create a menu bar wil tooltips. It seems to work for my list icons, but not for my settings icon. I guess it has something to do with specifying my elements within CSS, but on the other hand I think something is wrong with my javascript code as well maybe. Can someone point me in the right direction perhaps?

```js
const menu = document.querySelector(".menu"); // get menu item for click event

menu.addEventListener("click", function () {
    expandSidebar();
    showHover();
});

/**
 * expand sidebar if it is short, otherwise collapse it
 */
function expandSidebar() {
    document.querySelector("body").classList.toggle("short");
    let keepSidebar = document.querySelectorAll("body .short");
    if (keepSidebar.length === 1) {
        localStorage.setItem("keepSidebar", "true");
    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem("keepSidebar");
    }
}

/**
 * show hover effect on sidebar
 */
function showHover() {
    const li = document.querySelectorAll(".short .sidebar li");
    if (li.length > 0) {
        li.forEach(function (item) {
            item.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
                const text = item.querySelector(".text");
                text.classList.add("hover");
            });
            item.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
                const text = item.querySelector(".text");
                text.classList.remove("hover");
            });
        });
    }
}

function showHover2() {
    const a = document.querySelectorAll(".short .sidebar .menusettings .settings a");
    if (a.length > 0) {
        a.forEach(function (item2) {
            item2.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
                const text2 = item2.querySelector(".text2");
                text2.classList.add("hover");
            });
            item2.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
                const text2 = item2.querySelector(".text2");
                text2.classList.remove("hover");
            });
        });
    }
}


/**
 * check local storage for keep sidebar
 */
function showStoredSidebar() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("keepSidebar") === "true") {
        document.querySelector("body").classList.add("short");
        showHover();
    }
}

showStoredSidebar(); // show sidebar if stored in local storage
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap");
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.container .sidebar {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: width 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.container .sidebar a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container .sidebar .sidebartop {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  height: 55px;
  width:100%;
}
.container .sidebar .sidebartop .logo {
  width: 70%;
}
.container .sidebar .sidebartop .logo img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.container .sidebar .sidebartop .menu {
  width:20%;
  text-align: end;
}
.container .sidebar .sidebartop .menu i {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
}
.container .sidebar .sidebartop .logo-mobile {
  display: none;
}

.container .sidebar nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.container .sidebar nav ul li {
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1.25rem 0;
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: background-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.container .sidebar nav ul li a {
  display: block;
}
.container .sidebar nav ul li a i {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.container .sidebar nav ul li a .text {
  position: relative;
  left: 1rem;
  top: -0.2rem;
}
.container .sidebar .menusettings .settings a .text2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 1rem;
  top: -0.2rem;
}
.container .sidebar .account {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: calc(100% - 2rem);
  position: relative;

}
.container .sidebar .account .avatar {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  width: 20%;
}
.container .sidebar .account .avatar img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
.container .sidebar .account .name {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
.container .sidebar .account .name h4 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container .sidebar .account .logout {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-align: end;
  margin-left:0.1rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
.container .sidebar .account .logout i {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.container .main {
  margin-left: calc(30% + 2rem);
  padding: 1rem;
}
.short .sidebar {
    width: 2.5%;
    text-align: center;
  }
.short .sidebar .logo, .short .sidebar .text, .short .sidebar .avatar, .short .sidebar .name {
    display: none;
}
.short .sidebar .sidebartop {
    display: block;
    height: 55px;
}
.short .sidebar .sidebartop .logo-mobile {
    display: none;
}
.short .sidebar .sidebartop .menu {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.short .sidebar .text.hover {
    display: block !important;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    color: #333;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    position: absolute;
    left: 4rem;
    top: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
.short .sidebar .text2.hover {
  display: block !important;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  color: #333;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: absolute;
  left: 4rem;
  top: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
  .short .sidebar .account {
    display: block;
  }
  .short .sidebar .account .logout {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .short .main {
    margin-left: calc(5% + 2rem);
  }
  
  nav {
    position: relative;
    height:25rem;
  }

.container .menusettings .settings a {
    display: block;
}
.container .menusettings .settings i {
    font-size:1.25rem;
}
.menusettings .settings span {
  margin-left:1rem;
} 
.menusettings {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-top:9rem;
}

/* Tooltip dashboard */

[tooltip] {
  position: relative;
}
[tooltip]::before,
[tooltip]::after {
  text-transform: none; 
  font-size: .8em; 
  line-height: 1;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
[tooltip]::before {
  content: '';
  border: 2px solid transparent; 
  z-index: 1001; 
}
[tooltip]::after {
  content: attr(tooltip); 

  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
    display: block !important;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    color: #333;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    position: absolute;
    left: 4rem;
    top: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
[tooltip]:hover::before,
[tooltip]:hover::after {
  display: block;
}
[tooltip='']::before,
[tooltip='']::after {
  display: none ;
}
[tooltip][flow^="right"]::before {
  top: 50%;
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-right-color: #333;
  transform: translate(.5em, -50%);
}
[tooltip][flow^="right"]::after {
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(100% + 5px);
  transform: translate(.5em, -50%);
}
@keyframes tooltips-horz {
  to {
    opacity: 3.9;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
  }
}
[tooltip][flow^="right"]:hover::before,
[tooltip][flow^="right"]:hover::after {
  animation: tooltips-horz 300ms ease forwards;
}
.texteditor {
 position: relative;
 left:200px;
 top:100px;
}

  @media (max-width: 844px) {
    .container .sidebar {
      width: 5%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .container .sidebar .logo, .container .sidebar .text, .container .sidebar .avatar, .container .sidebar .name {
      display: none;
    }
    .container .sidebar .sidebartop {
      display: block;
      height: auto;
    }
    .container .sidebar .sidebartop .logo-mobile {
      display: block;
    }
    .container .sidebar .sidebartop .logo-mobile img {
      height: auto;
      width: 80%;
    }
    .container .sidebar .sidebartop .menu {
      display: none;
    }
    .container .sidebar nav ul li {
      padding: 0;
    }
    .container .sidebar nav ul li a {
      padding: 0.6rem 0;
    }
    .container .sidebar .account {
      display: block;
    }
    .container .sidebar .account .logout {
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .container .main {
      margin-left: calc(5% + 2rem);
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 390px) {
    .container .sidebar {
      width: 8%;
    }
    .container .sidebar nav ul li {
      padding: 0;
    }
    .container .sidebar nav ul li a {
      padding: 2rem 0;
    }
    .container .main {
      margin-left: calc(8% + 2rem); 
         }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Software/softwarenew.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebartop">
                <div class="logo">
                </div>
                <div class="logo-mobile">
                    <img src="/images/mobile.svg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="menu">
                    <i class="bi bi-arrow-bar-right"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="bi bi-house"></i><span class="text">Home</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i><span class="text">Draft</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="bi bi-sliders"></i><span class="text">CPQ</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="bi bi-calendar"></i><span class="text">Calendar</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="bi bi-receipt"></i><span class="text">Invoice</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
         <div class="menusettings">
             <div class="settings">
               <span tooltip="Settings" flow="right"> 
                <a href="#"><i class="bi bi-gear"></i><span class="text">Settings</span></a>
               </span>
             </div>
            <div class="account">
                <div class="avatar">
                    <img src="/images/avatar.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="name">
                    <h4>The DevDrawer</h4>
                    Adminstrator
                </div>
                <div class="logout">
                    <a href="#"><i class="bi bi-box-arrow-left"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            [page content here]
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/Software/softwarenew.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i ran your code but i dont seem to see any tooltip when hovering (or even clicking) on the sidebar items.

Comment: Yes stack gives an error apparently when using my code, but when you run it in a separate environment it should work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify all your three files. The changes are below,

- Modify class="text2" for Settings in html

---

```
<div class="settings">
  <a href="#"><i class="bi bi-gear"></i><span class="text2">Settings</span></a>
</div>
```

- Add function call to showHover2() in addEventListener in JS

---

```
menu.addEventListener("click", function () {
    expandSidebar();
    showHover();
    showHover2();
});
```

- Add the below codes in your css

---

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap");

body {
  color: #333;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.container .sidebar {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: width 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.container .sidebar a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container .sidebar .sidebartop {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  height: 55px;
  width:100%;
}
.container .sidebar .sidebartop .logo {
  width: 70%;
}
.container .sidebar .sidebartop .logo img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.container .sidebar .sidebartop .menu {
  width:20%;
  text-align: end;
}
.container .sidebar .sidebartop .menu i {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
}
.container .sidebar .sidebartop .logo-mobile {
  display: none;
}

.container .sidebar nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.container .sidebar nav ul li {
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1.25rem 0;
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: background-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.container .sidebar nav ul li a {
  display: block;
}
.container .sidebar nav ul li a i {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.container .sidebar nav ul li a .text {
  position: relative;
  left: 1rem;
  top: -0.2rem;
}
.container .sidebar .menusettings .settings a .text2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 1rem;
  top: -0.2rem;
}
.container .sidebar .account {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: calc(100% - 2rem);
  position: relative;

}
.container .sidebar .account .avatar {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  width: 20%;
}
.container .sidebar .account .avatar img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
.container .sidebar .account .name {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
.container .sidebar .account .name h4 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container .sidebar .account .logout {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-align: end;
  margin-left:0.1rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
.container .sidebar .account .logout i {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.container .main {
  margin-left: calc(30% + 2rem);
  padding: 1rem;
}
.short .sidebar {
    width: 2.5%;
    text-align: center;
  }
.short .sidebar .logo, .short .sidebar .text, .short .sidebar .avatar, .short .sidebar .name {
    display: none;
}
.short .sidebar .menusettings .text2 {
    display: none;
}
.short .sidebar .sidebartop {
    display: block;
    height: 55px;
}
.short .sidebar .sidebartop .logo-mobile {
    display: none;
}
.short .sidebar .sidebartop .menu {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.short .sidebar .text.hover {
    display: block !important;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    color: #333;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    position: absolute;
    left: 4rem;
    top: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
.short .sidebar .menusettings .settings .text2.hover {
    display: block !important;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    color: #333;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    position: absolute;
    left: 4rem;
    top: -0.5rem;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
  .short .sidebar .account {
    display: block;
  }
  .short .sidebar .account .logout {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .short .main {
    margin-left: calc(5% + 2rem);
  }
  
  nav {
    position: relative;
    height:25rem;
  }

/* .container .menusettings .settings a {
    display: block;
} */
.container .menusettings .settings i {
    font-size:1.25rem;
}
.menusettings .settings span {
  margin-left:0rem;
} 
.container .menusettings {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-top:9rem;
}
```

Hope it helps.